# Http Post Angular 9 Params

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, curl, post, httpclient

I tried to post my email and password on login method but every time get empty params after response

With curl, I sent it and everything worked

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post))
```

where $post

```
array('email'=>'some@gmail.com', 'password'=>'somepass')
```

But when i tried post from angular i get nothing

```
const params = new HttpParams();
params.set('email', 'some@gmail.com');
params.set('password', 'somepass');


this.http.post('https://myurl.com/login', '', {
   params: params
}).subscribe((data) => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Write code like below-

```
const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: { email: some@gmail.com, password: somepass, anotherParam: value}});
```

In your case following also might work.

```
const params = new HttpParams()set('email', 'some@gmail.com').set('password', 'somepass');
```

You can see request header in network tab like below
[image]

Comment: still empty values:
email: ""
password: null. const params = new HttpParams().set('email', 'some@gmail.com').set('password', 'somepass');

    this.http.post('https://myurl.com/login', '', {
      params: params
    }).subscribe((data) => console.log(data))

Comment: are you checking values from response? Check values in request payload. If you are not getting those parameter values in response then backend code should return those as a response. Not much angular app can do in this case

Comment: how can i get the request?

Comment: Updated answer. Make sure there are values for email and password in Query String Parameters sections

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

need to set header and params in body

```
const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('email', user.email)
      .set('password', user.password);

    this.http.post('https://myurl.com/login',
      body.toString(),
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      })
```